# Using Greek Letters - Symbols in regular text (LyX)

Tags: lyx, greek

I have been having trouble in writing Greek letters like: μ,α in regular text when using LyX.

When I try to include the package "babel-greek" the programme does not compile the pdf file.

I checked the other threads but I could not find a solution for this easy problem.

My preamble is:

```
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Greek works well for me out-of-the-box on Ubuntu. Before using special packages, are you able to compile simple Greek documents where you do not need to add anything to the preamble? Assuming you can, can you also compile more complicated Greek documents that we know work on other systems (ie mine): Can you compile the Greek Introduction in LyX? It is in the directory doc/el/Intro.lyx. Can you compile the Greek splash file (this is the file that shows up the first time you start LyX if your system language is Greek)? It is in the directory examples/el/splash.lyx. They all work well for me.

Comment: In the future, please also add a "lyx" tag. Otherwise people without knowledge of LyX might not see this question (I often only follow questions with the LyX tag) and don't even see the other questions. I just happened to see yours this time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's probably better to compile with `xelatex`  and load `fontspec` (it's for ordinary text in Greek,, isn't it?)

Comment: @mgulcur I agree with Bernard. Note that the manuals and examples above work with both pdflatex and xelatex.